# Converting CFM input type image to bootstrap button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, input, types

I am trying to add bootstrap to a cfm website. I'm encountering the problem of switching an image that is serving as a button to the bootstrap button feature.

Right now, the cfm page is saying

```
<cfif IsDefined("Form.Find_Address")>
        <INPUT name="Find_Address" maxlength=100 size="50" type="Text" value="#HTMLEditFormat(Form.Find_Address)#"> 
    <cfelse>
        <INPUT name="Find_Address" maxlength=100 size="50" type="Text"> 
    </cfif>


    <input type=image src="../images/b_find.gif" name="find" title="Find" border=0 alt="Find">
```

I want to switch the input type="image" to bootstraps button so I tried doing

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="find" title="Find" alt="find">Find</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has to do with HTML and CSS, not any ColdFusion syntax.

Are you sure that the Bootstrap CSS was loaded onto this page? An input of type image is an alternate to a Submit button. Maybe your button needs to be of type="submit"? Otherwise, it's just a button with no events mapped to it.

`<input type=image src="../images/b_find.gif" name="find" title="Find" border=0 alt="Find">`

should be replaced with

`<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="find" title="Find" alt="find">Find</button>`

Comment: Yes that worked, I had everything I was just missing the type="submit". Thank you so much!